# XCode 4.2.1 Crashes Every Time a New Window is Opened

Tags: xcode

I have Xcode 4.2.1 for Lion and it crashes everytime I open anything in a new window (so - for example - double-clicking on any file).  In this case, the type doesn't matter.  It will crash for .h, .m, .xib, .plist, etc....  I have re-installed Xcode to no avail.  This didn't happen until recently - but once it happened once - it keeps happening.

It doesn't appear to have anything to do with the items that are currently open - as I have closed all of them and opened a new project - and I still see the issue.

**UPDATE:** See my answer below for how I finally got this resolved.

Here is the exception I am getting:

```
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSUnknownKeyException): [<__NSCFConstantString 0x7fff7e9e38e0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key file://localhost/Projects/SomeProject/SomeFile.plist.
UserInfo: {
    NSTargetObjectUserInfoKey = "";
    NSUnknownUserInfoKey = "file://localhost/Projects/SomeProject/SomeFile.plist";
}
Hints: None
Backtrace:
  0  0x00007fff979c426a __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation)
  1  0x00007fff983acd5e objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib)
  2  0x00007fff97a4e4c9 -[NSException raise] (in CoreFoundation)
  3  0x00007fff8f9a8783 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForUndefinedKey:] (in Foundation)
  4  0x00007fff8f8df462 _NSGetUsingKeyValueGetter (in Foundation)
  5  0x00007fff8f8df3e9 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKey:] (in Foundation)
  6  0x00007fff8f8df101 -[NSArray(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKey:] (in Foundation)
  7  0x000000010a2ced12 -[IDEWorkspaceDocument _defaultPrimaryEditorFrameSizeForDocumentURL:] (in IDEKit)
  8  0x000000010a307d62 -[IDEWorkspaceWindowController _changeSizeForSimpleEditorWindowLayoutWithEditorDocumentURLOrNil:workspaceTabController:] (in IDEKit)
  9  0x000000010a30827d -[IDEWorkspaceWindowController _revertForNewWindowWithTabStateContext:documentURL:simpleEditorWindowLayout:completionBlock:] (in IDEKit)
 10  0x000000010a2cf795 -[IDEWorkspaceDocument _makeTabbedWindowControllerWithStateFromTabController:documentURL:simpleEditorWindowLayout:frontmost:completionBlock:] (in IDEKit)
 11  0x000000010a2f4188 +[IDEEditorCoordinator _doOpenIn_NewWindow_withWorkspaceTabController:documentURL:usingBlock:] (in IDEKit)
 12  0x000000010a2f4c41 +[IDEEditorCoordinator _doOpenIn_SeparateWindow_withWorkspaceTabController:documentURL:usingBlock:] (in IDEKit)
 13  0x000000010a2599ba +[IDEEditorCoordinator _doOpenWithWorkspaceTabController:editorContext:target:allowFallback:documentURL:usingBlock:] (in IDEKit)
 14  0x000000010a2f4dd5 +[IDEEditorCoordinator _doOpenEditorOpenSpecifier:forWorkspaceTabController:editorContext:target:takeFocus:] (in IDEKit)
 15  0x000000010a259353 -[_IDEOpenRequest _runIfNecessary] (in IDEKit)
 16  0x000000010a258d3a -[_IDEOpenRequest _enqueueForEventBehavior:] (in IDEKit)
 17  0x000000010a258855 +[IDEEditorCoordinator _openRequestForEditorOpenSpecifier:workspaceTabController:editorContext:eventBehavior:takeFocus:] (in IDEKit)
 18  0x000000010a2587ac __99+[IDEEditorCoordinator _openEditorOpenSpecifier:forWorkspaceTabController:eventBehavior:takeFocus:]_block_invoke_0 (in IDEKit)
 19  0x000000010a258740 _performBlockInsideReentrantGuard (in IDEKit)
 20  0x000000010a2586b5 +[IDEEditorCoordinator _openEditorOpenSpecifier:forWorkspaceTabController:eventBehavior:takeFocus:] (in IDEKit)
 21  0x000000010a25839d +[IDEEditorCoordinator openEditorOpenSpecifier:forWorkspaceTabController:eventType:] (in IDEKit)
 22  0x000000010a2579a1 -[IDEOutlineBasedNavigator _openNavigableItem:eventType:] (in IDEKit)
 23  0x00007fff979b3a1d -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] (in CoreFoundation)
 24  0x00007fff8df32710 -[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:] (in AppKit)
 25  0x0000000109b1fd10 -[DVTApplication sendAction:to:from:] (in DVTKit)
 26  0x000000010a207cf4 -[IDEApplication sendAction:to:from:] (in IDEKit)
 27  0x00007fff8df32642 -[NSControl sendAction:to:] (in AppKit)
 28  0x000000010a25776f -[IDENavigatorOutlineView sendAction:to:] (in IDEKit)
 29  0x00007fff8df98f48 -[NSTableView _sendAction:to:row:column:] (in AppKit)
 30  0x00007fff8df95d0f -[NSTableView mouseDown:] (in AppKit)
 31  0x00007fff8e313592 -[NSOutlineView mouseDown:] (in AppKit)
 32  0x000000010a256274 -[IDENavigatorOutlineView mouseDown:] (in IDEKit)
 33  0x00007fff8defb0e0 -[NSWindow sendEvent:] (in AppKit)
 34  0x00007fff8de9368f -[NSApplication sendEvent:] (in AppKit)
 35  0x000000010a207a11 -[IDEApplication sendEvent:] (in IDEKit)
 36  0x00007fff8de29682 -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)
 37  0x00007fff8e0a880c NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)
 38  0x0000000109901eec (in Xcode)
 39  0x0000000000000002
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for me ended up being a combination of multiple factors.  For some reason, Xcode 4.2.x was facilitating the problem.  I finally upgraded to Xcode 4.3 - but the problem still occurred.  After clearing out the preferences for Xcode (after updating) the problem went away.  I tried this numerous times with Xcode 4.2.x - but even clearing the preferences wouldn't solve the problem.

I'm glad to have this resolved - but I don't know how to resolve without upgrading to Xcode 4.3.

Answer (score 2):

The stack trace shows an `NSArray` object which is sent the `valueForKey:` message with the key `"file://localhost/Projects/SomeProject/SomeFile.plist"`. This just sends `valueForKey:` to each object in the array. One of the objects is an empty `NSString` which has just the default `NSObject`'s implementation of `valueForKey:`, which naturally doesn't know anything about the above key (`@"file://..."`) so it throws an exception.

The method sending `valueForKey:` to the NSArray is
`-[IDEWorkspaceDocument _defaultPrimaryEditorFrameSizeForDocumentURL:]` in IDEKit.

So I disassembled this method in IDEKit (/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDEKit.framework/Versions/A/IDEKit) using the [hopper disassembler](http://bsr43.free.fr/Hopper/).

What I concluded is that this method reads an NSArray from Xcode's `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefault]`, from the key `@"IDEDefaultPrimaryEditorFrameSizeForPaths"`. This array is then sent the `valueForKey:` with your file's path, hoping to find the frame size for the file's editor but instead causing the error. The problem is probably that somehow this `NSUserDefaults` entry became invalid (Either it's an `NSArray` with unexpected content, or it's not even supposed to be an `NSArray`).

So, there's a good chance clearing Xcode's preferences will help, as suggested by @RAZ :-)
(It's not certain it will help, as the user defaults can be registered by Xcode at runtime - but it might).

An alternative (less interesting but pragmatic :-) ) solution is to reinstall Xcode to a location other than the default. When you install, you can choose a custom install folder. This will install a fresh copy of Xcode side by side next to your original.

Comment: Unfortunately clearing out all of the prefs didn't work.  I'm going to try the new install shortly.

Comment: Try from terminal: `defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode`. Make sure to quit Xcode first.

Comment: I did try that earlier - and it did not fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Reset your simulator, it can cache bad data after an upgrade.

I have also seen people fix misbehaving apps by clearing apps prefs

http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20001229001847541

just backup first, you said you reinstalled but some installers do not reset prefs.

Comment: It doesn't occur in the simulator - it occurs in Xcode.  It happens when the simulator isn't even running.

Answer (score 0):

I've been  having similar issues in Xcode myself and I'm seeing a few ppl around forums experiencing bugs related to Xcode itself. it might help repairing disk permissions, but I can't really confirm it. but worth the try

Answer (score 0):

Just a shot in the dark, does it happen in a new user account?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I fixed mine:

- Go -> Home -> Autosave Information -> all xcode related files send to
  trash
- Finder -> empty trash
- Apple -> restart